# PassportJS Node: why need serializeUser and deserializeUser even when not using session?

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

```
exports.initPassportLocalStrategy = function () {
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
      session: false
    },
    function(username, password, done) {
      UserProxy.validateUserWithPassword(username, password)
        .then(function (user) {
          if(user) done(null, user);
          else done(null, false);
        })
        .catch(done);
    }
  ));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    cb(null, user);
  });
};
```

I'm implementing a token based auth middleware without seesion. So I was wondering why do I need to provide a `serialzeUser` function? I have read that the reason is to put user or some of its properties into the session and then `desearlizeUser` would retrieve the whole object from the session and put it in the `req.user` .

So here are my questions:

1. Why can't the done(null, user); in the `LocalStrategy` function put the user into `req.user` ? Why even bother serialise and deserailie?
2. If remove the `searlizeUser` function I will get an error, but I can get away without a `deserilzeUser` function, why? And in this case, who puts the user object to `req.user`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need serialize/deserialize. Your setup is slightly wrong.
You need to move the `session: false` out of the strategy and into `passport.authenticate`. This is because strategies can't decide this, it's rather dependent on your route which kind of authentication you want.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    UserProxy.validateUserWithPassword(username, password)
      .then(function (user) {
        if(user) done(null, user);
        else done(null, false);
      })
      .catch(done);
  }
));
app.use(passport.initialize());  
app.post('/auth', passport.authenticate(  
  'local', {
     session: false // here goes the session false
  }), doWhateverYourSetupNeeds);
```

Comment: Why do we need a `passport.initialize()` when we don't use sessions.